# location of database created by the application

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I have opened a database using sqlite3 in my application. When i run the application in the simulator, this database might be created and i'm playing with it. But now i need to know the location (to be accessed from ma mac) where this database is created. Surely it is not in the application folder as i'm not seeing it. I doubt it to be somewhere in the location where the simulator is installed. Anyone knowing the location. pls help me finding it.

Comment: without knowing where the db file is created, how do you even connect to it?

Comment: i'm creating and connecting from within the application. I was confused where it is being created. nevan have given the answer which i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the actual file on your Mac, try looking in this folder:

`/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/`

There should be a bunch of folders with long names. If you've recently built your app for the Simulator, order the folder by Date and the newest will be at the top. The folder contains a Documents folder, but you can also right-click on the app to "Show Package Contents", which might contain your `database.sqlite` file.